# How to make PHP regex to match text inside a HTML <label>

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build PHP regex that will match ONLY the text inside a HTML `label`.

In the example below it should match the `Blah blah blah` text contained inside the `<label>` tags.

Also the `for` and `id` attributes of the `label` change often, so I can't match based on those.

```
<li class='gchoice_3_4_0'>
    <input name='input_4' type='radio' value='gquiz4330f6f1q'  id='choice_3_4_0' tabindex='28'   />
    <label for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Blah blah blah</label>
</li>
```

For far this is the best I've come up with: `<label(.*?)>(.*?)<\/label>`

But it's matching the entire HTML `label` element (`<label for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Blah blah blah</label>`) instead of just the text inside (`Blah blah blah`).

Comment: So, what's wrong with the outcome? The two capture groups? // Also, what's the rationale for not using a DOM traversal library (e.g. `qp($html)->find("label")->text()`), other than performance?

Comment: @mario, the outcome is that it's matching the entire HTML label element (`<label for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Blah blah blah</label>`) instead of just the text (`Blah blah blah`). Updated question to make that more clear. I don't know what a DOM traversal library is, looking into that now.

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant, if you can simply look at the second capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it matches more than your text because you have two `(.*?)` match groups.

What's wrong with this?

```
<?php

$str = "<label for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Blah blah blah</label>";

preg_match("~<label(.*?)>(.*?)<\/label>~", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

echo $matches[2]; // Prints Blah blah blah
```

Or if you want to replace:

```
<?php

$str = "<label for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Blah blah blah</label>";

echo preg_replace_callback("~<label(.*?)>(.*?)<\/label>~", function($matches) {
   return "<label $matches[1]>Replaced</label>";
}, $str); // prints <label  for='choice_3_4_0' id='label_3_4_0'>Replaced</label>
```

Comment: The first group can be made non-capturing